# Android component to impelent a listview with tabbed headers

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design

Is there any standard Android material view that is the best fit for the implementation of such a layout?

[image]

In this layout, I mean to have a tab group on top when one of them is touched/clicked then the related list can be shown on the list below.

It is some sort of implementation for a list with two levels of items. The headings are on top and sub-headings are at the bottom ListView.

Both lists (tabs on top, and list items on bottom) are dynamically populated and their number is not fixed.

Comment: Certainly there are views that can implement such layout but first can you explain in detail the behaviour you want to achieve in the said layout. thanks.

Comment: @SyedAtifAli Details are added

Answer (score 0):

You can use tablayout with viewpager and fragments
There are plenty of resources are available you can look into [this](https://medium.com/busoft/how-to-use-viewpager2-with-tablayout-in-android-eaf5b810ef7c) as well.
In fragments set your list according to your use case. i.e., if you setting them statically then put directly in fragments.
or if you are getting through api then use viewmodel and set them dynamically.